# Doesen't work LIKE icontains

Tags: python, mysql, django

Try do search with ajax requests.

```
    prefix = str(request.POST.get('prefix'))
    colors = UserDataCsv.objects.filter(material__icontains=prefix).values('color')
    print(colors.query)
```

But i don't get response, coz:

```
    SELECT `users_userdatacsv`.`color` FROM `users_userdatacsv` WHERE `users_userdatacsv`.`material` LIKE %ff% ORDER BY `users_userdatacsv`.`id` ASC
```

I haven't quotes in mysq SQL reqyest `%ff%`, how i can fix it?
Use django 1.9

Comment: Can you please provide what the value of `prefix` is and the error when you get if you do `print(colors)`?

Comment: prefix = value from input for example `ff` error i can't get data from databases and when i do `print(colors.query` and then insert SQL query in SQL console get error `[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%ff% ORDER BY `users_userdatacsv`.`id` ASC' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct

```
 column LIKE string_constant
```

requires a properly defined string constant.  You probably want

```
  users_userdatacsv.material LIKE '%ff%'
```

with the string constant `%ff%` wrapped in `'` single quotes.

Comment: yeap... why python don't add quotes for LIKE construction?